# How to connect Raspberry Pi (3B+) to Google Cloud IoT

Tags: google-cloud-platform, raspberry-pi3, google-cloud-iot

I am a beginner to IoT and Cloud IoT especially. I came across this link, which describes, how we can connect a sensor to Google Cloud IoT core, using Raspberry Pi as a gateway

https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-iot-gateways-rpi

I implemented every step carefully. I found here n there some Python 2 vs Python 3 print statement errors... which I fixed somehow

But after doing everything, I am able to only send, but it is getting stuck at waiting for response... basically my Raspberry Pi is not connected to Google Cloud...

Is there any better tutorial for connecting Raspberry Pi to Google Cloud or what all steps I should be careful, so I can connect my Raspberry Pi to GCloud, using same tutorial, which I shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have an easier time starting from the [basic Python sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/iot/api-client/mqtt_example) instead of the more complex Gateway demo.

You should first [create a registry and device](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/devices), next you can connect using the Python sample and the device credentials.

If NodeJS is more familiar to you, you can try [the quickstart from here](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/quickstart).

I will see about updating the community article, we really shouldn't have the legacy print statements in there. You can try to start from what I've done so far here:

```
git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community
```

Comment: thank you so much! for your valuable information. I am a complete beginner for this. So i will try your solutions and update the status. Can you please recommend me a tutorial, which i can use to send simple sensor data to Gcloud..like dht11 temperature data etc

Comment: @saikumar the code was just republished and I have verified it works

Comment: Thank you so much for updating the content. Will check and report if I find any issues

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem.
I followed carefully same tutorial https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-iot-gateways-rpi

I created a gateway on VirtualMachine - it turned out its IP wasn't visible in my local network. I changed the settings of the network to Bridge Adapter on the VM and turned off firewall on my PC - that helped. Once I was able to ping my gateway's address all worked fine.